# How can HtmlHelper::script() handle filenames with more than one dot (e.g. myscript.min.js)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

In my view, when including a script using `<?php echo $this->Html->script('script.js'); ?>` everything works fine. However, if I change the filename to 'script.min.js', the URL renders fine, but CakePHP refuses to serve the script and instead returns this:

```
Warning (2): include(/home/example/public_html/app/View/Themed/Type1/webroot/js/script.min.js): failed to open stream: Permission denied [CORE/Cake/Routing/Filter/AssetDispatcher.php, line 161]
Warning (2): include() [http://php.net/function.include]: Failed opening '/home/example/public_html/app/View/Themed/Type1/webroot/js/jquery.min.js' for inclusion (include_path='/home/example/public_html/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') [CORE/Cake/Routing/Filter/AssetDispatcher.php, line 161]
```

I tried both `<?php echo $this->Html->script('script.min.js'); ?>` and `<?php echo $this->Html->script('script.min.js', array('plugin' => false); ?>` but none worked so far.

What is the workaround for this?

Comment: try to omit the .js: `echo $this->Html->script('script.min');`. But it seems it wrongly tries to load a themed asset here.

Comment: Clever, but still not working. It seems to me that HtmlHelper cannot accurately discriminate between relative urls, [plugin syntax](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/glossary.html#term-plugin-syntax) and [dot notation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/glossary.html#term-dot-notation).

Comment: Possible. You can open a ticket for this at github. I am sure that will then be addressed.

Comment: Just for the records: HtmlHelper works properly. Here's the [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/2316), in case somebody else runs into the same issue.